# Bulk upsert in MongoDB using Morphia. Is it possible?

Tags: java, mongodb, import, morphia, upsert

I have an entity implemented by a POJO, let's call it `TestEntity` that is saved in a Collection in Mongo. I generate instances of this entity by iterating over a CSV file and inserting OR updating an existing record if some conditions are met. Below you can find some sample of my code

```
// File is parsed into an entity
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
Mapper w2sMap = new Mapper();
w2sMap.addMappedClass(TestEntity.class);
morphia = new Morphia();

Datastore datastore = morphia.createDatastore(client, w2sMap, "test");

// SaveTask implements Runnable
@Override
public void run() {
try {
   datastore.save(testEntity);
} catch (DuplicateKeyException ex) {
   if (updateConditions) // Query Mongo to find the entity, change some fields and save
   else // Log
}
```

The SaveTask is run by an ExecutorService by multiple threads each saving one instance of TestEntity. However some of the CSV files are enormous and many `save` operations have to be performed which is cumbersome (750k saves are executed in roughly 10 minutes on my machine). One solution is to store `TestEntity` in an `Iterable` Collection and fire a save task every now and then on the collection, thus reducing network latency and increasing performance (My actual MongoDB is run on a different server)

However the problem rises when I try to use bulk insert cause I still get exceptions when a duplicate key is found. I know about `new InsertOptions().continueOnError(true)` however I need to be able to upsert documents in one go, this will simply ignore duplicated entries.

Is there anyway around this or do I need to catch the exceptions, find out which objects were NOT saved and keep going from there? I can provide a better code example if requested.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options to try:

1. Save with a [write concern](http://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html?is-external=true) of 0 "Don't wait for acknowledgement from the server", i.e. `datastore.save(testEntity, WriteConcern. UNACKNOWLEDGED);`. This is fast but will ignore errors because it doesn't wait for a server ack.
2. You already considered saving multiple objects in one go with [save(...)](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.3/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/Datastore.html#save-java.lang.Iterable-org.mongodb.morphia.InsertOptions-) but you could try the WriteConcern there too.
3. You can use the [Java bulk writes](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/bulk-writes/) to have more control, e.g.

```java
  DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("user");
  BulkWriteOperation bulk = coll.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
  bulk.find(new BasicDBObject("z", 1)).upsert().update(new BasicDBObject("$inc", new BasicDBObject("y", -1)));
  bulk.find(new BasicDBObject("z", 1)).upsert().update(new BasicDBObject("$inc", new BasicDBObject("y", -1)));
  bulk.execute();
```

Your example code doesn't show how you are using upserts, but in general you should always catch exceptions and handle them yourself.